# ReactJs Cannot get value of an object from FETCH

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have implemented fetch and set it into object. However, when I want to get its value. It shows undefined, I have no idea about this. Here is the code.

```
import {useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import { useRouter, Router } from 'next/router';
import Layout from '../../components/MyLayout';
import Settings from '../../components/Settings';

const Post = (props) => {

  const [object, setObject] = useState({});
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(
    () => {
      const data = router.query;
      const FormData = new URLSearchParams();
      FormData.append('slug',data.id);
      fetch(Settings.api+'viewPost',{
        method: 'POST',
        body: FormData
      })
        .then(res=>res.json())
        .catch(function(e){
            console.log(e)}
        )
        .then(obj=>{
            setObject(obj.data[0])
        })
    }
    , [router.query]
  )
  return (
    <Layout>
     <h1>{object.title}</h1> --> I would like to display here
    </Layout>
  );
}

export default Post;
```

Anyway here is the json I would like to implement

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "total": 0,
  "data": [
    {
      "postId": 4,
      "boardId": "",
      "username": "test@email.com",
      "title": "How To Make Money",
      "slug": "how-to-make-money",
      "answer": 0,
      "checked": 0,
      "status": "",
      "waktu": "2019-10-16 04:45:30"
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

I really appreciate any answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try just logging `console.log(object)`, You already set the value of the `object` state as whatever `obj.data[0]` was.

EDIT: You can probably get away with doing a check before the useEffect gets triggered:

```
if (!object) {
  return <h1>Loading...</h1>
}

console.log(object.data[0])
return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>{router.query.id}</h1>
    </Layout>
  );
```

Comment: console.log(object) works fine. However, I would like to get value inside its object. It can only works at "object.data". If I go further than that, it does not works ex (object.data[0]). Anyway, I just added json output to help you understand more. Thank you anyway

Comment: I see it. I was confused by the comment. When you log it does it get logged twice?

Comment: That is a problem during initial render. `object` = `{}`.

Comment: Right. UseEffect will trigger after the mount so the initial value will be `{}`, but it should set the new value.

Comment: Maybe you need to do a check before the return `if (!data) return <h1>Loading...</h1>`

Comment: So, what should I do anyway to get its value? I have no idea about that. Been searching many times but do not get the answer. Or should I change UseEffect method? Do you have any alternative?

Comment: check my edited comment. Does your code actually just break?

Comment: I don't get it, could you rewrite my code in order to display the value?

Comment: I did. Check my original post. I edited it. Your useEffect only triggers after the jsx gets mounted to the DOM. Your jsx will get rendered first, so its running before you give your object value. That's why you're getting an undefined. You need to have a way to render a loading message when object is waiting to be given a value. And that only happens during useEffect which is ran after everything else.

Answer (score 2):

```
import {useEffect,useState} from 'react';
import { useRouter, Router } from 'next/router';
import Layout from '../../components/MyLayout';
import Settings from '../../components/Settings';

const Post = (props) => {

const [object, setObject] = useState({});
const router = useRouter();

useEffect(
   () => {
     const data = router.query;
     const FormData = new URLSearchParams();
     FormData.append('slug',data.id);
     fetch(Settings.api+'viewPost',{
       method: 'POST',
       body: FormData
     })
     .then(res=>res.json())
     .catch(function(e){
         console.log(e)}
     )
     .then(obj=>{
         setObject(obj.data[0])
     })
 }
, [router.query]
)
//console.log(object.data[0]); --> does not work here
return (
  <Layout>
    <h1>{router.query.id}</h1>
  </Layout>
);
} 

export default Post;
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But whats the different to set 'obj' directly instead of 'obj.data[0]'. Does it not support multiple nested JSON?

Answer (score 1):

This might the problem when it is getting rendered initially. 
Before the api call it might not have data.

You need to check it before using that

```
{ object && object.data[0]}
```

or you can show loading when you dont have data

```
if (!data) return <span>Loading...</span>
```